Scatter xaxisScaleMin first date seems incorrect
I import through CSV and array for which X is a date at format "2024-10-23T17:20:53".
The file contains one week of samples each minute
var allDates=csv.getCol(0);

then I draw a Scatter with
xaxisLabelsCount: 7,
xaxisScaleMin: allDates[0],
xaxisScaleMax: allDates[nSamples-1],

All the dates are correct except the first one:
Without formatting dates:

With formatted dates (T:):


Can you put the page online so that I can take look at it?

Or post a sample of the allDates array.

It is at https://malaise.hd.free.fr/meteo/Serv.html
I can provide the data file, but I don't know how.

Ok, I've added what will hopefully be a fix for this to the core library which you can get here from GitHub:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heyesr/rgraph/refs/heads/main/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js
Let me know how it works out for you.
